# Adding a column characters based on file name in R

Tags: r, csv

I have several hundred files regarding information in .pet files organized by date code (19960101 is format YYYYMMDD). I'm trying to add a column, NDate with the date code:

```
for (pet.atual in files.pet) {
  data.pet.atual <-
    read.table(file = pet.atual,
               header = FALSE,
               sep = ",",
               quote = "\"",           
               comment.char = ";");     
    data.pet.atual <- cbind(data.pet.atual, NDate= pet.atual)
}
```

What i'm trying to achieve, for example, is for the 01-01-1996 NDate = 19960101, for 02-01-1996 NDate = 19960102 and so on. Still the for loop just replaces the NDate field everytime it runs with the latest pet.atual, ideas? Thanks

Comment: You should probably use `lapply` instead of a for loop with a growing set of columns.

Comment: It's not only the`NDate` field which is overwritten in each pass of the `for` loop but also `data.pet.atual`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Small modification should do the trick:

```
data.pet.atual <- NULL
for (pet.atual in files.pet) {
    tmp.data <-
    read.table(file = pet.atual,
               header = FALSE,
               sep = ",",
               quote = "\"",           
               comment.char = ";");     
    tmp.data <- cbind(tmp.data, NDate= pet.atual)
    data.pet.atual <- rbind(data.pet.atual, tmp.data)
}
```

You can also replace the `tmp.data<-cbind(...)` by `tmp.data$NDate <- pet.atual`

Answer (score 2):

You may also try `fread()` and `rbindlist()` from the `data.table` package (untested due to lack of a reproducible example):

```
library(data.table)
result <- rbindlist(lapply(files.pet, fread), idcol = "NDate")
result[, NDate := anytime::anydate(files.pet[NDate])]
```

`lapply()` "loops" over all entries in `files.pet` executing `fread()` for each entry and returns a list with the data.tables `fread` has created from reading each  file. `rbindlist()` is used to combine all pieces into one large data.table. The parameter `idcol = NDate` generates an index column named `NDate` to identify the origin of each row in the final output. The ids are integer numbers 1 to the length of the list (if the list is not named).

Finally, the id number is used to lookup the file name in `files.pet` which is directly converted to class `Date` using the `anytime` package.
**EDIT** Perhaps, it might be more efficient to convert the file names to `Date` first before looking them up:

```
result[, NDate := anytime::anydate(files.pet)[NDate]]
```

Although `fread()` is pretty smart in analysing and guessing the right parameters for reading the files it might be necessary (and perhaps faster as well) to supply additional parameters, e.g.:

```
result <- rbindlist(lapply(files.pet, fread, header = FALSE, sep = ","), idcol = "NDate")
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, lapply will help, as Frank suggests. And you want to use rbind to keep the dates different for each file. Something along the lines of:

I'm assuming files.pet is a list of all the files you want to include...

```
my.fun<-function(file){
data <- read.table(file = file,
           header = FALSE,
           sep = ",",
           quote = "\"",           
           comment.char = ";")     
data$NDate = file
return(data)}

data.pet.atual <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, lapply(files.pet, FUN=my.fun))
```

I can't test this without a reproducible example, so you may need to play with it a bit, but the general approach should work!